# Serialize objects and parents in one-to-one relationship in django

Tags: django

I have two models : domain and speciality, where domain is a foreignkey in speciality:

```
class Domain(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Speciality(models.Model):
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In my views, I do a filter on speciality, so I would obtain a queryset with all specialities and their domains, each object individually. I would like to serialize to obtain something like this:

```
{ object1 : { 'domain' : 'Computer science',
              'specialities' : { {'pk': '1', 'name':'Programming'},
                                 {'pk': '2', 'name':'Networking'} 
                               }
            },
  object2 : { 'domain' : 'Mathmatics',
              'specialities' : { {'pk': '3', 'name':'Algebra'},
                                 {'pk': '4', 'name':'Geometry'} 
                               }
            }
}
```

So basically, I want to serialize from the child to the parent, instead of what I usually see: from parent to child. 
I can't see to do that with django ModelSerializer. Is there a way of doing it, or should I do it manually.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760455/django-rest-framework-how-to-serialize-one-to-many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done using ModelSerializers.

Try something like this,

```
class SpecialitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Speciality
        fields = '__all__'


class DomainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    specialities = SpecialitySerializer(source='specialities', many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Domain
        fields = ('name', 'specialities',)
```

Use the DomainSerializer for your query.

Also you have to set a related_name for your ForeignKey constraint in the Speciality model(which would be "specialities").